# sqlite LEFT OUTER JOIN multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, outer-join

In this example we have 3 related tables on a SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    c1 integer,
    primary key (c1)
);
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    c1 integer,
    c2 integer,
    primary key (c1, c2)
);    
CREATE TABLE test3 (
    c2 integer,
    c3 integer,
    primary key (c2)
);
```

Now I need to join all tables:

```
 test1 -> test2 (with c1 column)
          test2 -> test3 (with c2 column).
```

I have tried this solution but it doesn't run:

```
SELECT 
   * 
   FROM test1 a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 b
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN test3 c
                          ON c.c2 = b.c2 
          ON b.c1=a.c1
```

It gives me an error:
 `near "ON": syntax error.`

Any help ?

Comment: Never used sqlite3, but the correct standard SQL syntax is LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON ... LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON ..., and not nested joins. )

Comment: I have used this syntax on Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLServer without any problem.

Comment: Nested joins - or `JOIN (one JOIN two JOIN three) ON (one.id = two.id AND two.some_id = three.some_id)`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a simple misplacement of your `ON` statement. This conforms to SQL standard:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 b ON b.c1=a.c1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test3 c ON c.c2=b.c2
```

This is explained in [further depth here.](http://web.archive.org/web/20141016200848/http://www.sql-server-pro.com/sql-join.html)

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel it runs fine.   I have used previous sql format for years.  But SQLite doesn't like it to much.

Comment: It's possible that specific (fancy?) implementations are able to parse it, but that SQLite just holds to the spec.