# Confusion over relationships in ER Modelling

Tags: sqlite, entity-relationship

I have a question. Basically I'm simulating a publisher's database which is full of author information. So to this effect I have an entity called 'Author' - author has a primary key of an autoincrementing counter, as well as a 'name' and a birth year.

In addition to this, I have entity for 'book' which has - again - a name, publishing year, it's own identifying primary key that is of an auto-incrementing counter. It also has two foreign keys - a field that references the primary author (which is required), as well as an optional field which specifies a secondary author.

My question is, clearly the relationship between author and book is 'one' to 'zero or more'. However, where I get stuck is the 'optionality' of the secondary author. I am thinking it should be a relationship of 'zero or one' to 'zero or more' but I'm not sure if I'm translating the logic correctly - my thought is that there is a possibility that many books will not have a secondary author.

Equally, when implementing this in sqlite3, is it best to make this field 'required' or 'optional'? I'm assuming if I make it required that it can remain dormant as a 'NULL' value unless needed.

Any help you can provide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship you are looking for is a many-to-many relationship.

- A book has 1 or more authors
- A person writes (authors) 1 or more books

This means that you'll need 3 database tables:

*books, people* and *authors*

- Books: id, title
- Authors: book_id, person_id, position (e.g. 1 for first author, 2 for second author)
- People: id, name

Once you have these three tables you can query the relationships using JOINs. A beginners intro to joins can be found in this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcrZoHselPk), the kind of JOIN you want is presented around the 4:50 mark.

A stackoverflow answer and example can be found here: [sqlite LEFT OUTER JOIN multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105895/sqlite-left-outer-join-multiple-tables)

Comment: thanks! what if I changed my relationship so that instead of having a 'secondary author' - I had an 'editor' who themselves are an author (but again would be optional). Does this corresponds to a 'zero or one' to 'zero or more' relationship?

Comment: That depends. I guess a book can have multiple editors. So than you get an extra table called editors. Or you can change the authors table to a books_people table and add a 'role' field.